# Package management strategy with Pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, package-management

Since I switched my favorite distro to Gentoo I have been very familiar with the following pattern for installing and removing packages:

1. Install a bunch of applications that do pretty much the same thing to try them out: `emerge <package>`. This command installs the package, and mark the package as explicitly installed.
2. Do try them out and remove those I don't like (and hopefully keep one or two that satisfy my needs): `emerge --deselect <package>`. This command removes the package from the list of explicitly installed applications, but does not uninstall the package.
3. Finally remove everything that is not required on my system: `emerge --depclean`. This command removes all packages that are (1) not a system package, (2) not installed explicitly and (3) not a dependency of those two.
4. And optionally check that all package dependencies are OK: `revdep-rebuild`. This command checks all dependencies and reinstall broken packages.

Once in a while I would look at the entries in `/var/lib/portage/world` (the list of explicitly installed packages) to review the **top-level** applications that I use, and remove those that I don't use anymore using the commands in step 2, 3 and 4.

Now that I'm trying to learn Arch, I wonder if I could use the same strategy with Pacman? Or another strategy that can keep my system **clean** of unused packages?

Note: the [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta) helps a lot in quickly understand things, but I could not figure out Arch's equivalent of the `/var/lib/portage/world` file. `pacman -Qe` is said to do it, but it contains things that I swear I haven't explicitly installed... Anyway please answer this question in terms of strategy (with command examples, of course :)

Comment: since arch is not a source distro you won't find an equivalent of revdep-rebuild I rarely find broken ones... but it happens... and then I just rebuild and reinstall with the pkgbuild and let arch devs know if that worked. happened to smplayer a few months back.

Comment: @xenoterracide Thanks for the info, but in this question I couldn't care less about revdep-rebuild :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to DarwinSurvivor's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6934/package-management-strategy-with-pacman/7010#7010) I have been able to better understand how package management works in Arch. Now I can apply the same strategy that I use with Gentoo (with small modifications). The "equivalents" of the commands in the question are, respectively:

1. `pacman -S <package>`
2. `pacman -D --asdeps <package>`
3. `pacman -Rs $(pacman -Qqtd)`
4. Not available / not needed

The closest thing to `/var/lib/portage/world` in Gentoo is the result of the command `pacman -Qe`. Differences:

1. Arch has [package groups](http://www.archlinux.org/groups/), which is basically several packages "grouped" together under a name. When a group is installed everything in the group is considered explicitly installed.
2. Arch doesn't have "system packages", so reducing items from the result of `pacman -Qe` can actually result in important packages being removed.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely reason you are seeing packages with `pacman -Qe` that you don't remember installing is that they were part of a "group" (like `base-devel`, etc) that you installed.

Side Note: I have personally also been looking for a while to switch a package from "explicit" to "implicit" (and even vice-versa) without reinstalling it, it even taking a package I installed explicitly to get another package working and turn it into a dependency of that package (again without reinstalling).

Comment: The point about `pacman -Qe` is interesting, I'm not familiar with the "group" thing. Regarding the side note, arent `--asdeps` and `--asexplicit` supposed to do just that?

Comment: @phunehehe No, pacman -Qe is a query (showing all explicitly installed packages) --asdeps and --asexplicit are sync options. --asdeps will INSTALL an application as a if it were a dependency. Since it is not actually required by anything, it will appear in a "pacman -Qdt" which lists all packages installed as dependencies that are no longer required by anything (usually those packages can be removed without consequence). The most confusing thing I found about pacman when I started (coming from ubuntu's apt-get/apt-cache) was that 1 utility was used for everything (behaviour changes with -S/-Q)

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly,

```
pacman -S package
```

installs a package

```
pacman -Rs package
```

removes a package and all its dependencies---but only those that wouldn't break other packages and only those that you didn't explicitly install.

Checkout the pacman man page.

I unfortunatly don't know how to check for broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the package manager to keep track of the explicitly installed packages, you could use a configuration management tool like Ansible on your system. I use that for my own few machine and I always can set up a machine just like my main machine with just two commands.